# Replacing Data in Array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am  working on an angular application. I have an array as follows:

```
[{ 
    "Name": "Andy"
}, 
{ 
    "Name": "Bayer"
}, 
{ 
    "Name": "James"
}, 
{ 
    "Name": "Doda"
}]
```

I have another array which containes data as follows:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Andy",
        "Id": "1",
        "Time": "2020-06-19T11:02+00:00"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Billy",
        "Id": "2",
        "Time": "2020-06-19T11:05+00:00"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ciena",
        "Id": 5
        "Time": "2020-06-19T11:05+00:00"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Doda",
        "Id": "4",
        "Time": "2020-06-19T11:05+00:00"
    }
]
```

I want a `resultant array` such that code should check if `Name` is present in `first array`, then it should copy data from `second array` for that `Name` and push it in `resultant array`. For example common name between above two array is **Andy** and **Doda**, so data from **Andy** and **Doda** should be pushed to `resultant array` as follows:

```
[{
    "Name": "Andy",
    "Id": "1",
    "Time": "2020-06-19T11:02+00:00"
},
{
    "Name": "Bayer"
}, 
{ 
    "Name": "James"
}, 
{
    "Name": "Doda",
    "Id": "4",
    "Time": "2020-06-19T11:05+00:00"
}]
```

At run time I may get many names so code should be generic. I was trying following code which I got over stackoverflow itself

```
this.newArray  = _.map(this.resultantArray, item => {
    const value = _.find(this.dataArray, ['Name', item]);
    const obj = value ? value : {Name: item};
    return obj;
});
```

But this code is not working as expected as it works fine for the first time but when data comes for second time it appends data to previous data. I want array to be populated again freshly every time I send data. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `vanilla JS` no need for lodash. You can first `map` it and inside that you can `find` the value from second array otherwise return the current `object`:

```js
var arrayTwo = [ { "Name": "Andy", "Id": "1", "Time": "2020-06-19T11:02+00:00" }, { "Name": "Billy", "Id": "2", "Time": "2020-06-19T11:05+00:00" }, { "Name": "Ciena", "Id": "5", "Time": "2020-06-19T11:05+00:00" }, { "Name": "Doda", "Id": "4", "Time": "2020-06-19T11:05+00:00" } ];

var arrayOne = [{ "Name": "Andy"}, { "Name": "Bayer"}, { "Name": "James"}, { "Name": "Doda"}];

var result = arrayOne.map(val=>arrayTwo.find(p=>p.Name==val.Name) || val);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: is result is an array?

Comment: @Admin yes, map will always give an `array`.

Comment: I wrote your code in a method returned result from that method. Result is not copying data. It is simply giving me list of names

Comment: and it is also appending data

Answer (score 0):

Suppose first `array` name is `First`

```
First : any [] = [{"Name": "Andy"},{"Name": "Bayer"},{ "Name": "James"},{"Name": "Doda"}]
```

And Second `array` name is `Second`

```
Second : any[] = [{"Name": "Andy","Id": "1","Time": "2020-06-19T11:02+00:00"},{"Name": "Bayer"},{"Name": "James"},{"Name": "Doda","Id": "4","Time": "2020-06-19T11:05+00:00"}]
```

Now do looping and check each name of `first` if its exists in `second` copy from `second` and push in `result array`

```
result : any[] =[];
this.First.forEach((element) => {
    let index = this.Second.findIndex((x) => element.Name== x.Name);
     if (index > -1) {
             let data = {
                         this.Second[index].Name,
                         this.Second[index].Id,
                         this.Second[index].time,
                        };
             this.result.push(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have only two arrays.

Comment: there is problem with logic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216890/discussion-between-wasim-and-admin).